# How to get CPTColor of a CPTFill object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

How can I get CPTColor of a CPTFill object?

Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `CPTFill` is a class cluster. Instances can be colors, gradients, or images, each of which is represented by a private subclass. A fill does not expose an API to determine its contents.